# code won't work across multiple worksheets (Tried moving selection, select, etc. and still wont work)

Tags: vba, excel

An Excel VBA newbie here. I am working on this code for a one-click-for-all worksheets macro. So the idea is to have a macro that once clicked, can trigger the IF-ISERROR-Vlookup formula in multiple worksheets (around 12 now, but will keep increasing in the future). Both the formula and the result are displayed in the same columns in multiple worksheets, but of different number of rows (Sheet 1 col B[data] and C[formula], sheet 2 Col B and C, etc.)

Now the code I did below works only when I go to a worksheet and trigger the macro in that specific worksheet; which means I have to do it one by one per sheet. 
I tried removing the select, the selection and the activesheet as recommended in previous posts, but it showed an error message to me.

So my questions are:

a) How can I modify the code so that I can create a macro that triggers all worksheets in one click?

b) As you can see below, I put Range("C4:C54") even though the number of rows are different in every sheet, because I have no idea how to make the range cover different rows only until it hits the last cell with values.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
     Range("C4").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],TestScore,1,FALSE)),""Pass"",""Fail"")"
     Range("C4").Select
     Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C4:C54")
     Range("C4:C54").Select
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Anybody can help with this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much beforehand!

Edit:
Added the sample snapshot of the problem as requested
[image: Click here for image.]

Comment: So... you are basically asking how to find the last used cell of a column? That is the most frequently asked, and answered, question here.

Comment: a) Put your code in the Module and use `With ws ... End With` then put `.` before `Range...`. b) Use LastRow. Just Google: LastRow in Excel

Comment: Basic problem is that your loop does not reference `ws` so will always refer to the active sheet which doesn't change.

Comment: No, the main thing I ask is how to trigger the macro across multiple worksheets, since the code I used above failed to do so. Finding the last used cell of a column is a part of the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in the Module (**Insert** >> **Module**):

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row      'Change the number (1) with appropriate column
            .Range("C4:C" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],TestScore,1,FALSE)),""Pass"",""Fail"")"
            'The formula will be filled down til the last row
        End With
    Next ws
```

Comment: Hi Anastasiya, thanks for your answer too! Your code works, but it has the same problem as what Tom's code does: instead of filling C4 to the last cell, it filled C1:C4. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: How about adding `+3` in the variable `LastRow`? So, you replace it with this `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 3`.

Comment: Hi Anastasiya, sorry for the late reply. I was out of town the last couple days. I tried your code, but it still won't work. It said "Cannot enter a formula for an item or field name in a PivotTable report." Why it thought I was doing a PivotTable, I had no idea. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give the pictures of your detailed sheet layout? Just put them in the question

Comment: I just posted the link to the image in my original answer as Stackoverflow didn't allow me to post images directly here yet.

Comment: Just change the code `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` to `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`. I made a modification there by changing the value 1 that indicates Column A to the value 2 that indicates Column B.

Comment: Hi Anastasiya, yes that seems to be the right fix, and thanks to you both my problem is solved! Upvoted your answer and again, thanks for helping me out, really appreciated that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `Select` statements - it can cause issues and instead refer to the cells explicitly. This will insert your formula in cells `C4` to the last cell in that column

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        .Range("C4:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],TestScore,1,FALSE)),""Pass"",""Fail"")"
    End With
 Next ws
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer! I used your code and it worked, but instead of going from row C4 to the last cell in that column, it filled cells C1 to C4. Do you have any idea how the code can be changed? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have less then 4 rows on your sheet?

Comment: Hi Tom, no, I have different numbers of rows in different sheets, but all of them have more than 4 rows. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: It was trying to find the last row in Column `C` which would be 4. Have updated to get the last row from Column `B` which I think is what you want looking at your picture

Comment: That totally works like a charm, thanks a lot Tom! Appreciate your help and have a great day!